# Node.js does not recognise angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have installed the angular package in my node.js project. But it does not recognise the angular keyword.

[image]

Comment: do you see any errors in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is it cannot find the angular.js reference. Just make sure the path you mentioned for angular library is right.

Here is the working Demo with same code,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function Customer($scope) {
      $scope.CustomerName = "abc";
      $scope.CustomerCode = "abc";
    }
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    myApp.controller("CustomerObj", Customer)
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="custScreen" ng-controller="CustomerObj">
    Email :
    <input ng-model="CustomerName" type="text"> <br>
    Password :
    <input ng-model="CustomerCode" type="pasword"><br>
    {{CustomerName}}<br/>
     {{CustomerCode}}<br/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: he is asking how to get angular from npm to work on his project.  you are giving him a cdn link.

Comment: @btinoco no i have asked him to check the path of angular.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have included angular js library in head section as

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```